# Реальные проекты на google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Всем привет.

Начинаю работу с google app engine, и мне хотелось бы посмотреть на реальные проекты, которые крутятся на этом сервисе. Желательно написанных на java, хотя думаю это не столь важно.

Если у кого есть ссылки, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Вот [один](https://www.ingress.com/) из проектов на google app engine.

Comment: Как Вы узнали, что он на app engine? Или это Ваш проект? Если Ваш, то у меня будет еще несколько вопросов) Спасибо)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402302/real-projects-on-google-app-engine/25403170?noredirect=1#comment39625608_25403170

Comment: @zamutil по заголовку server